# displaying name instead of the id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I developed a page that shows all the truck plate number in a table and the plate number when you click them each they go to this page and display the data related to that plate number my problem is displaying the name of the truck it just displays the first truck plate number on every page of different trucks I click but, the data displayed are working correctly I am just having trouble displaying what truck plate number the data's that are being shown

I am displaying the plate number through here `<?php echo $row['truck_plate_no'];?>` but it only displays the first plate number This is my code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/connect.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

 mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
 $query_join = "SELECT * FROM tbl_delivery_details, tbl_truck WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck=tbl_delivery_details.tbl_truck_id_truck ORDER BY tbl_delivery_details.id_delivery_details";
 $join = mysql_query($query_join, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
 $row_join = mysql_fetch_assoc($join);
 $totalRows_join = mysql_num_rows($join);

   $id_truck = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id_truck']);



  $sql_PK = "SELECT * FROM tbl_delivery_details WHERE tbl_truck_id_truck = {$id_truck}";
  $PK = mysql_query($sql_PK, $connect);
  if ( mysql_error() ) {
   die ( mysql_error());
 }
  $row_PK = mysql_fetch_assoc($PK);

  $truck_id = $row_PK['tbl_truck_id_truck'];



 $truck_id = mysql_real_escape_string($truck_id);



 $sql = "SELECT tbl_truck.truck_plate_no, 
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_route, 
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_destination, 
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_van_no, 
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_waybill_no, 
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_charge_invoice,
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_revenue,
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_strip_stuff,
     tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_date

 FROM tbl_truck, tbl_delivery_details 

 WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck = tbl_delivery_details.tbl_truck_id_truck
 ORDER BY tbl_truck.truck_plate_no"; 



 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

 $sum = 0;
 $sum1 = 0;

 ?>



 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/x  html">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Truck Delivery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qcc.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.ico">
 </head>

 <body>

 <div id="logo">
         <a href="home.php" title="QCC Corporation"><img src="images/logo_comp.jpg" width="245" height="105" alt="QCC Corporation"></a>
     </div>
     <div id="nav">
         <a href="form.php">Add-Transactions</a>
         <a href="truck.php">Truck</a>
         <a href="driver.php">Driver</a>
         <a href="customer.php">Customer</a>
         <a href="fuelsource.php">Fill-up-source</a>
         <a href="report.php">Reports</a>
     </div>
     <div id="border">
        <hr />
     </div>

 <div id="content"><table border="1" table align="center">
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>Route</th>
           <th>Destination</th>
           <th>Van No.</th>
           <th>Waybill No.</th>
           <th>Charge Invoice</th>
           <th>Revenue</th>
           <th>Strip/Stuff</th>


         </tr>

   <?php do { ?>
     <tr>

       <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_date']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_route']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_destination']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_van_no']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_waybill_no']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_charge_invoice']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_revenue']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row_PK['delivery_details_strip_stuff']; ?></td>
       </tr>

             <?php $revenue = $row_PK['delivery_details_revenue'];
                    $sum += $revenue;
              ?>

              <?php $strip = $row_PK['delivery_details_strip_stuff'];
                    $sum1 += $strip;
              ?>
            <?php } while ($row_PK = mysql_fetch_assoc($PK)); ?>
        </table>
  </div>
 <div id="revenue">
     Total Revenue: <?php echo $sum;?>
 </div>
     <div id="strip">
     Total Stripping/Stuffing: <?php echo $sum1;?>
     </div>
     <div id="head">
      <?php echo $row['truck_plate_no'];?>
     </div>
  </body>
  <div id="footer">
         <br/><br/>Copyright © 2013 WFJCC. All rights reserved.
 </div>
 </html>
 <?php
 mysql_free_result($join);
 ?>
```

Comment: How many rows should there be?

Comment: i dont want it to be put into the tables i just want to display what truck plate number the data's belong to and put them on the top part of the page

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: i will look into mysqli and pdo

Comment: but can anyone point me to the error in my code why it doesnt display the plate number that is supposed to be shown instead it displays the first plate number in the plate number table?

Answer (score 0):

In your query

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_truck.truck_plate_no, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_route, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_destination, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_van_no, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_waybill_no, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_charge_invoice,
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_revenue,
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_strip_stuff,
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_date

FROM tbl_truck, tbl_delivery_details 

WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck = tbl_delivery_details.tbl_truck_id_truck
ORDER BY tbl_truck.truck_plate_no";
```

The WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck = tbl_delivery_details.tbl_truck_id_truck seems to be incorrect as you should be doing it based on the $truck_id instead which is causing the  to show the first plate number.

```
WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck = $truck_id
```

---

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_truck.truck_plate_no, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_route, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_destination, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_van_no, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_waybill_no, 
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_charge_invoice,
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_revenue,
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_strip_stuff,
 tbl_delivery_details.delivery_details_date

FROM tbl_truck, tbl_delivery_details 

WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck = $truck_id
ORDER BY tbl_truck.truck_plate_no";
```

Comment: what should i put? instead of WHERE tbl_truck.id_truck = $truck_id

Comment: You don't have that currently..  you need to go from what you have and probably replace it with what I listed..  currently it is not pointing to the $truck_id